# Is there a way to require a T to be a member of a union type?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a union type `type Foo = Bar | Baz`, and an array of foos (`Array<Foo>`). Is there a way to write a filter function which extracts only a certain type from the array in a type safe way?

Something like the following, but specify that `T` must be a member of `Foo`. So that for example `onlyFoosOfType(x, Number)` won't typecheck.

```
class Bar {}
class Baz {}

type Foo = Bar | Baz;
var a: Array<Foo> = [];

function
onlyFoosOfType<T>
( arr  : Array<Foo>
, ctor : new(...args) => T
): Array<T> {
    return <Array<T>> arr.filter(x => {
        return x instanceof ctor;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully working example that accepts `Bar` or `Baz`, but rejects the other class I created as an example.

The salient point is the generic type constraint: `T extends Foo`.

TypeScript is awesome enough to accept the union types, but not other types... except of course if they are structurally identical (i.e. if I created another class that looked exactly like the `Bar` class or exactly like the `Baz` class, that would be allowable. This makes sense as it would also allow me to use that type in the `Array<Foo>`.

```
class Bar {
    constructor(public num: number){}
}

class Baz {
    constructor(public num: number){}
}

class Example {

}

type Foo = Bar | Baz;
var a: Array<Foo> = [
    new Bar(1),
    new Baz(2),
    new Bar(3),
    new Bar(4)

];


function onlyFoosOfType<T extends Foo>(arr  : Array<Foo>, ctor : new(...args) => T): Array<T> {
    return <Array<T>><any> arr.filter(x => {
        return x instanceof ctor;
    });
}

var example1 = onlyFoosOfType(a, Bar);
// "[{"num":1},{"num":3},{"num":4}]"
console.log(JSON.stringify(example1));


var example2 = onlyFoosOfType(a, Baz);
// "[{"num":2}"
console.log(JSON.stringify(example2));

// Error: Example is not a Foo!
var example3 = onlyFoosOfType(a, Example);
```

Just to demonstrate the point, here is a version where the `Example` class could be used...

```
class Bar {
    constructor(public num: number){}
}

class Baz {
    constructor(public num: number){}
}

class Example {
    constructor(public num: number){}
}

type Foo = Bar | Baz;
var a: Array<Foo> = [
    new Bar(1),
    new Baz(2),
    new Bar(3),
    new Bar(4),
    new Example(5)
];

var example4 = onlyFoosOfType(a, Example);
// "[{"num":5}"
console.log(JSON.stringify(example4));
```